# Use the grep functie to find words which contain either blue of red

Tags: r

Im using the grep function to select certain column heads. The heads I want to select should contain exactly "red" or "blue"

I got the red thing to work using (I stored the columnnames in a variable called x) ->

```
x <- c("Red", "Blue", "blue", "green")

grep("^red$", x, varnames=TRUE)
```

But i cant figure out how to look for red OR blue... Any thoughts?

```
grep("^(red|blue)$", x, varnames=TRUE)
```

This doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Please show some example to test. `grep('^((?i)red|blue)$', x, value=TRUE)` or `grep('^(red|blue)$', x, ignore.case=TRUE)`

Comment: Do you need the grep to match `Red`, `Blue` or is it just `red` or `blue`?  Also, you are using `varnames=TRUE` which is not an argument in `grep`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the search is not supposed to be case-sensitive, then I'd suggest the following:

```
> x <- c("Red", "Blue", "blue", "green")
> grep("^(red|blue)$",tolower(x))
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep("red|blue", x, ignore.case=T, value=T)  # returns [1] "Red"  "Blue" "blue"
```

If you require the match to be case-sensitive, remove the `ignore.case=T`.

If you require a case-sensitive match to the entire string (which is what you get when you use the assertions `^` and `$`) then you are basically asking for `x[x=="blue"|x=="red"]`, which may be more efficient than a regex.